# How to take a list of strings that comprise of several different URLs and convert them into clickable links on R?

Tags: r, string, list, dataframe, url

I currently have a variable that contains over 1000 different strings of website URLs however they are all in strings so are not clickable or anything. Is there a function (or set of steps) to which I can convert all of those string of URLs into actual clickable URLs on R.

My goal is to then make a data frame with all of those and merge it in to another data frame, but I'll worry about that part later :)

Comment: This doesn't really make sense.  "Clickable" only makes sense in a certain context.  Are you talking about when printing out to the console? Are you making a shiny app? In what context do you want this to be "clickable"?

Comment: Shiny app, yes.

Comment: What do you mean by printing out to the console? Essentially, I will be taking this data frame I am creating and having it on a website. My goal is for the data frame to include links to the all the additional websites.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: There isn't much reproducibility other than I have a variable that I want to change into a clickable link. i.e. 
urls <- c("website1here", "website2here", ... "website1000here")

Comment: Yeah well you'll get more help if you do the work of setting up the extremely basic shiny files so that others don't have to do that just to get to a point to show you what needs to be done.  I'm just trying to help but you'll get more help if you put in more effort.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with how to work with Shiny as this is my first time if I'm being honest. Could you show me a thread or give me some pointers on how to set it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R itself isn't a web browser and so doesn't have any concept of "clickable links". If you just want the link functionality, the easiest method is to create an html page that you can open in a browser. You can do this in R as follows.

```
    UrlVec <- c("https://stackoverflow.com/url_A",
       "https://stackoverflow.com/url_B",
       "https://stackoverflow.com/url_C")

    cat("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n<title>Links document from R</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>My Links</h1>\n",
    paste0("<p><a href=\"",UrlVec,"\">Link ",seq_along(UrlVec),"</a></p>",collapse="\n"),
    "\n</body>\n</html>\n",file="C:/Path/Links Page.html")
```

This uses a paste0 to construct the html links in UrlVec, and embeds the result in a very simple template for a web page. This is written to the file "C:/Path/Links Page.html". Open that file in a web browser, and you ought to have clickable links.